# Ghostscript changed Orientation from landscape to portrait

Tags: ghostscript

I have a PDF file that I need to change the orientation from landscape to portrait, using this command GS. The Orientation switch it is not changing the orientation. Is there a extra setting I need to add?

```
::Path to your Ghostscript EXE
set GSC="C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin32.exe"

%GSC% -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="D:\TRANS\PDF\2_ZNOR_00000000000000000070.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice" -f "D:\TRANS\PDF\1_ZNOR_00000000000000000070.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
List<string> switches = new List<string>
        {
            "-empty",
            "-dQUIET",
            "-dSAFER",
            "-dBATCH",
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-dNOPROMPT",
            "-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=612",
            "-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=792",
            "-dFIXEDMEDIA",
            "-dFitPage",
            "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
            "-dAutoRotatePages=/None",
            "-sOutputFile=" + resultFilePath,
            "-c",
            "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice",
            "-f"
        };

        switches.Add(this.FilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the switches you are using there will have no effect at all, and you haven't done anything to rotate the PDF file either.

The first thing to note is that Ghostscript is really the wrong tool for this job, it doesn't *modify* PDF files, it generates completely new ones. The process is described [here](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

The -dEPSCrop switch only has an effect if the input is an EPS file, otherwise it does nothing.

The operands to setpagedevice are incorrect, you are passing an empty hex string `<>` when setpagedevice expects a dictionary `<<>>`. Even then an empty dictionary will do nothing.

I expect you intended to put `<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice` but actually that's only a media matching request. In order to get Ghostscript to create a rotated PDF file you would have to alter the media size, set it to fixed, and set -dFitPage. You would also have to set the AutoRotatePages switch to None in order to prevent the automatic reorientation of the output so that the text is horizontal.

Since you haven't supplied the PDF file to look at, nor stated its media size, I can only guess at the sizes. However, something like

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=new.pdf -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=792 -dFitPage -dAutoRotatePages=/None input.pdf
```

Comment: The PDF page size is 11.00x8.5  ins, what is the dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS and the dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS switch for ?

Comment: The DEVICE*POINTS switches set the media to a fixed dimension (I forgot to add -dFIXEDMEDIA, you'll need that too). This **is** all in the documentation. If you want to change 11x8.5 to 8.5x11 then you'll need to transpose the numbers, WIDTH=612 HEIGHT=792.

Comment: Thanks for the help @KenS, I am able to RotatePages but it is getting cut off at the top and the page size is 8.5x8.5.

Comment: Its kind of hard to understand what you mean without an example, but it sounds like you have on of the dimensions wrong or something. Or possibly you are using an old version of Ghostscript. Oh, you are, try upgrading.